# Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590) in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am new to nodejs and I cannot solve following problem: Error message : Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590).I write the project in vs code in ubuntu but so far started giving such error. In project and VS code using the same ts version.
Error source code:

```
export const markAsNotified = async (instance, courier, order, searchDistance) => {
    await NotifiedCourierModel.create({
        order_number: order.number,
        courier_id: courier.courier_id,
        courier_token: courier.push_token,
        distance: searchDistance,
        sent_at: new Date(),
    });
};
```

NotitfiedCourierModel:

```
import { getModelForClass, modelOptions, prop, index } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

@modelOptions({
    schemaOptions: {
        collection: 'notified_couriers',
    }
})
@index({ sent_at: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 * 60 }) // expire in 30 minutes
export class NotifiedCourier {

    @prop({ required: true })
    order_number!: number;

    @prop({ required: true })
    courier_id!: string;

    @prop({ required: true })
    courier_token!: string;

    @prop({ required: true })
    sent_at!: Date;

    @prop({ required: true })
    distance!: number;

    public static async findByCourier(courierId: string, orderNumber: number, currentDistance: number) {
        return NotifiedCourierModel.findOne({
            courier_id: courierId,
            order_number: orderNumber,
            distance: { $lte: currentDistance }
        }).exec();
    }

    public static async findNotAssignedCouriers(assignedCourierId: string, orderNumber: number) {
        return NotifiedCourierModel.find({
            courier_id: { $ne: assignedCourierId },
            order_number: orderNumber
        }).exec();
    }

}

export const NotifiedCourierModel = getModelForClass(NotifiedCourier);
```